# Create and use anonymous object in PHP

Tags: php, object, anonymous

Say I have a simple class and I create it and call a function on it like this:

```
class tst
{
  private $s = "";

  public function __construct( $s )
  {
    $this->s = $s;
  }

  public function show()
  {
    return $this->s;
  }
}

$t = new tst( "hello world" );
echo "showing " . $t->show() . "\n";
```

Is there any syntax or workaround that will allow me to instantiate an instance of tst and call the show() function without assigning the object to a variable? I want to do something like:

```
echo new tst( "again" )->show();
```

I don't want to declare my functions as static as I want to use them in both of the above examples.

Comment: What advantage does `tst::create(x)->show()` over just using `x`?!? Or `f(x)` if there's actually some work (validation, normalization, conversion) ones in the constructor?

Comment: @delnan: Your question is equivalent to asking "why use classes in programming?". A more relevant question (but one which I feel is adequately answered by the OP) is "why not make the methods static?".

Comment: @Jon: Rest assured that I know, understand and appreciate OOP. But wrapping something in this class, which does nothing, and then retrieving the wrapped value instantly, seems pretty useless. The equivalent of `(function (x) { return x; })(x)` in JS, if you will. And even if the constructor did something useful with that value, there's no need to wrap the result in an extra object.

Comment: @delnan: I see, and of course I agree with you. But I believe the OP is just giving us an example here; that's probably not what the real class does.

Comment: @delnan - I take your point, the example does nothing useful. It was the simplest code to illustrate what I wanted to do and my real code does not have simple show() functions but others that actually manipulate the variable passed in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want exactly, but there are workarounds without making things static.

You can make a function that returns the new object

```
function tst( $s ) {
    return new tst( $s );
}

echo tst( "again" )->show();
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

```
public static function create( $s )
{
    return new tst($s);
}

public function show()
{
    return $this->s;
}
```

The above will allow you to do `tst::create("again")->show()`. You can rename `create` as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted Galen's as it results in slightly cleaner syntax.

Comment: @SteveClaridge: Regardless of the accept, I feel that having an extra free function (with a parameter list that needs to be kept in sync with the class constructor) in order to save 5 keystrokes is not the best approach. But it's your code, your decision.

Answer (score 1):

[Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) uses this approach everywhere. It uses add() method wrapper which is defined for global object ancestor. Here is some real-life code:

```
$page
    ->add('CRUD')
    ->setModel('User')
    ->setMasterField('admin',false);
```

This code creates 'CRUD' view, puts it on the page, creates and links with Model_User class instance which receives additional condition and default value for boolean 'admin' field.

It will display a CRUD control on the page with add/edit/delete allowing to edit all users except admins.

Here is code to describe concept:

```
class AbstractObject {
    public $owner;
    function add($class){
        $c=new $class;
        $c->owner=$this;
        return $c;
    }
}

class Form extends AbstractObject {
    function dosomething(){
        return $this;
    }
}
class OtherForm extends Form {}

$object->add('Form')->dosomething()->owner
       ->add('OtherForm');  // etc
```

I think it's awesome and very practical approach.

p.s. I have to note new syntax for exceptions:

```
throw $this->exception('Something went bad');
```

using $this links exception to the object, which is at fault, which also can set default class for exception.